# Objective-C: efficient way to count objects in categories

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, dictionary

I have a bunch of objects in a set of categories. I'd like to know how many of each category of there are.

In another language, I'd make a dictionary, then iterate over the objects, incrementing the appropriate value in the dictionary for each one. However, because I can't store a native numeric type in an NSDictionary in Objective-C, this has me constantly converting back and forth between NSNumber and a numeric type:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (MyObject *obj in objs) {  
    NSNumber *old = [dictionary objectForKey:obj.category];
    NSNumber *new = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1 + old.integerValue];
    [dictionary setObject:new forKey:obj.category];
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you have the array `obis` sorted by category?

Comment: Have you profiled this and found it to be a significant bottleneck? Especially considering that `NSNumbers` with small integer values are cached (and may be implemented as tagged pointers on some platforms),  you really do need to have benchmarks and targets in place before optimizing something like this.

Comment: Sorry @vikingosegundo, I don't mean "category" in the Objective-C sense. It's just some arbitrary value like "species" or "color". You're right, I should have used a different word.

Comment: @warrenm: I'm not that worried about it being a bottleneck, I'm really just hoping that someone has an awesome Objective-C idiom that handles this well, since counting things like this seems to come up a lot in my code.

Comment: The awesome Objective-C idiom is to use NSNumber. Because it's almost never a bottleneck, there's no reason not to do it. Except for verbosity, which ObjC typically hasn't worried about (although Apple keeps adding new features to remove some of those problems).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSCountedSet *bag = [[NSCountedSet alloc] init];
for (MyObject *obj in objs) {  
    [bag addObject:obj.category];
}
for (id category in bag) {
    NSLog(@"%d instances of %@", [bag countForObject:category], category);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: In my case, I want to [bag addObject:obj.category], not the object itself, but that works perfectly.

Comment: @Aneel Fixed it, for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSMutableData to store your counters:

```
int                 * count;
NSMutableData       * num;
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary;

dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (MyObject *obj in objs)
{
    if ((count = [[dictionary objectForKey:obj.category] mutableBytes]) == nil)
    {
        num    = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:sizeof(int)];
        count  = [num mutableBytes];
        *count = 0;
        [dictionary setObject:num forKey:obj.category];
    };
    *count += 1;
};
```

This prevents the dictionary from being modified and a new `NSNumber` from being allocated each time a category's count is updated

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a bottleneck, you can use the underlying CFDictionaryRef instead of NSMutableDictionary, to create a dictionary that stores integers directly, instead of boxing them in NSNumber values.

Read the documentation on CFDictionaryCreateMutable and CFDictionaryValueCallBacks for details, but the basic idea is that your retain and release do nothing, your description generates an NSNumber on the fly (or just does an stringWithFormat:"%d"), and your equal compares the ints directly.

Here's a sample showing the tricky parts of the code:

```
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

CFStringRef intdesc(const void *value) {
  int i = (int)value;
  CFNumberRef n = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &i);
  CFStringRef s = CFCopyDescription(n);
  CFRelease(n);
  return s;
}

Boolean inteq(const void *value1, const void *value2) {
  int i1 = (int)value1, i2 = (int)value2;
  return i1 == i2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CFDictionaryValueCallBacks cb = { 0, NULL, NULL, &intdesc, &inteq };

  CFMutableDictionaryRef d = 
    CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL,
              0,
              &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
              &cb);
  CFDictionarySetValue(d, @"Key1", (void *)1);
  CFDictionarySetValue(d, @"Key2", (void *)2);
  CFStringRef s = CFCopyDescription(d);
  NSLog(@"%@", s);
  CFRelease(s);
  CFRelease(d);
  return 0;
}
```

If you're gong to do a lot of this, you should probably wrap this up in ObjC (especially if you're using ARC), but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If this turned out to be a big time-waster, you could:

- create an array of all the unique categories
- use its count to create a C-style array of int types
- match the category of each incoming object, getting an array offset, and increment the corresponding int bucket
- (optimize the category look-up as necessary, if that became a new bottle-neck)

But I certainly agree with the commenter who said, essentially, to measure first.